# "One of my family" VS "one of my family members"

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Which of these is correct?

> He is one of my family.
>
> He is one of my family members.

Would there be a better way to put this?

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please show any research you may have done while framing this question. If you need assistance in this, please see our Help page on ["Asking a question"](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

***He is one of my family members*** is fine. 
***He is one of my family*** is awkward.

More natural usage would be:

> ***He is a member of my family.***

Or:

> ***He is part of my family.***

Or:

> ***He is in my family.***

Or, even simpler:

> ***He's family***.

Comment: A different example. if put as:  "he is one of the family" would frequently suggest he was not actually a family member but "he is- like- one of the family".   My dog,  he is one of the family.  My sister's friend Diane was at our house so often and has remained so close,  she's we treat her like one of the family.  Your first example isn't quite like that but it's close enough and awkward enough that it might leave someone asking what you mean exactly.

Comment: True, good point. To that end, I would probably veer off into a completely different sentence, something like: "He's related to me," or, "He's my brother," or, "He's a relative of mine." Something more specific to forestall any possible confusion.

Comment: I meant the op's first example by the way . I plus +1'd your explanation..  and  yeah,  I also think you're right in your comment to me

Comment: Cool, appreciate it! You know, after this exchange, you feel like family to me! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Both are okay (by which I mean "Both *sentences* are okay").  "He is one of my family" can be taken as short for "He is one member of my family".  The principle is like the one I used above in the first sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> He is one of my/the family

should mean exactly what it says but as tom pointed out, it very often means

> He is treated as one of my/the family

By contrast

> He is one of my family members

appears to mean the same and is not incorrect but it's a very unusual phrase. To really convey that meaning would need a different idiom, as for instance,

> …a member of my family

It's much more likely to be heard in answer to a question, as for instance:

> Who told you that?
>
> One of my family members

or more likely

> A member of my family

and either way, very likely to be followed by something like

> I don't remember who actually said it…